# Adding a div using jQuery then connecting it via jsPlumb

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb for the first time and would appreciate some help with it.

My application allows the user to create a "balloon" (a div) at the click of a button, and then draws a string from the balloon to a "handle" (another div) using jsPlumb.

The following code works on my browser (FF) if I remove the .show effects, but if I include the `{effect: "scale", percent: "100"}`, the connector gets drawn and then disappears straight afterwards.

HTML:

```
<div id="my_window">
  <div id="my_balloons">
    <div id="my_handle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="my_buttons">
    <div class="button">Make a balloon</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my_balloons {
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#my_handle {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 42%;
  top: 90%;
}

.button {
  background-color: #2460a4;
  border-radius: 0.9em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 7em;
}

.balloon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  width: 100px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

JS:

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {

  jsPlumb.on(document, "click", ".button", function() {

    var balloon = '<div id="my_balloon" class="balloon hide">Balloon!</div>';
    $('#my_balloons').prepend(balloon);
    $('#my_balloons .balloon').show({
      effect: "scale",
      percent: "100"
    });

    jsPlumb.connect({
      source: "myBalloon",
      target: "my_handle",
      anchors: ["BottomCenter", "TopLeft"],
      endpoint: "Dot"
    });


  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a division using

```
 $("#container").on('click', '.btnClass', function (e) {   
     var balloon = $('<input>').attr('type', 'text');
     balloon_parent.append(balloon);
```

}

Here, the container is the balloon's parent canvas.
Then you can use this input and add it as a text to your handle div.
In order to obtain the input from the balloon div the following code should be included as well

```
balloon.keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $(this).parent().text(this.value);
            }
        });
        balloon.focus();
```

Comment: If what you needed to do is to add a division that retrieves user input upon button click, this should work

Comment: I'm not retrieving user input, I want to allow the user to create a balloon div upon button click. This part works. What doesn't work is 
$('#my_balloons .balloon').show({
      effect: "scale",
      percent: "100"
    });
unless I remove the 
{ effect: "scale", percent: "100" }

Comment: I _think_ it has something to do with the fact that the BottomCenter anchor point for the connector effectively moves as the scale effect on show() is implemented. I tried introducing a delay between the show() and jsPlumb.connect() methods, like this:

Comment: setTimeout(
                        jsPlumb.connect({
                            source: myBalloon,
                            target: "hand",
                            anchors: ["BottomCenter", "TopCenter"],
                            endpoint: "Blank",
                            paintStyle: {strokeStyle: "lightgray", lineWidth: 2}
                        }), 
                        1000);

but that didn't work. Perhaps I'm not using setTimeout() correctly?